# How to force gdb to view at a given address

Tags: python, gdb, heap-memory

I'm trying to view python variable with gdb.

```
(gdb) python print(hex(id(a)))
0x7f3ca4f68c20
(gdb) x 0x7f3ca4f68c20
0xa4f68c20: Cannot access memory at address 0xa4f68c20
```

Could someone explain me why gdb is trying to access `0xa4f68c20` when I asked it to look at `0x7f3ca4f68c20`?

Thanks.

Comment: is your debugger a 32-bit debugger? you need a 64-bit debugger to be able to view such addresses. can you type "show version" in gdb prompt?

Comment: It's all 64 bits. `file $(which gdb)
/usr/bin/gdb: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64...`

Comment: and the version of the debugger ? (show version)

Comment: gdb --version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git. And python is not relevant here, actually, just plain ` x 0x7f3ca4f68c20` cause this strange behavior. Is this a bug?

Comment: looks that address gets moduloed to 32 bits... looks very much like a bug... unless the debugged process is 32 bits, doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: /usr/bin/python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object

Thank you, I'll report this bug.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `(gdb) show architecture` ?

Comment: Could you show us the arguments you gave to gdb when you started it? I'm not clear on what you're trying to debug. `(gdb) python print(hex(id(a)))` will print the address of `a` in gdb's embedded CPython interpreter, but the `x` command is going to try to fetch data from another process.

Comment: `gdb show architecture` shows i386 (set automatically), which is very strange, as all on my machine is amd64 (x86_64). And for python stuff, thanks for clarification. I though it running core in the debugging process. Nevertheless, it's a strange behavior for gdb (auto to i386 on pure x86_64 arch).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your gdb is attached to a target process (as is usually the case), you are looking at the wrong memory space.
`id(a)` gives object address in gdb's memory space, while `x` command looks into target memory space.

If your case, the target seems to also be a 32 bit process, which is why your addresses are truncated.